# World Clock in Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm Wondering if it's possible to show all country time in wp7.5 without using internet ?

for example :

i have Listbox for Country...when i select one country form ListBox, there is Textbox will show me current time of that country.

```
Give me answer to do that, 
1st option : without using internet
2nd option : using internet
```

thanks

Comment: Hardcode the timezones(or use http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone to save them to local storage). Then make a list of countris for every timezone. Then set a time and GMT +/- the timezone for the selected country. Best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in my opinion, u cant do without using internet, because in this case, the app work everytime on background and thats impossible.
the other choice is the best.
u can learn rss reader and find world clock site for rss.